# True alternative to exec() in python

Tags: python-3.x

So, I have been trying to execute a concatenated string in Python 3 and it worked. This function would eventually go into a (while) loop, where the loop counts up to the current month.

```
def all_installs_to_dataframe(month):
    '''Imports csv's from different months to pandas dataframes'''
    command = ["dataset = pd.read_csv('/path/file2017", "_overview.csv', sep=',', header=0, encoding='utf-16')"]
    return (command[0] + month + command[1])
exec(all_installs_to_dataframe("05"))
```

However, on my extensive research on Stackoverflow it seems like `exec()` is not liked (except for trustworthy input). Hence, I would like to know how to do this better? I found that many are fond of dictionaries, I tried this and it would give me a string as well:

```
dict = {'start': "dataset = pd.read_csv('/path/file2017", 'month': "05", 'end': "_overview.csv', sep=',', header=0, encoding='utf-16')"}
exec(dict['start']+dict['month']+dict['end'])
```

Which I would have to `exec()` again.
So, how could I do this without using the `exec()` statement?

@nico: I initially had this loop over all my files (with datetime library):

```
month_date = 3
while month_date - 1<date.today().month:
    dataset = "dataset_%s" % (month_date)
    function = "pd.read_csv('/path/file2017%s_overview.csv', sep=',', header=0, encoding='utf-16')" % (month_date)
    dataset = function
    month_date += 1
```

Then I realized that I get a string and it won't work. So I am using the `exec()` function now. But everywhere I read I shouldn't use it, so how could I circumvent the `exec()` function in this loop?

Comment: Is there a reason you're not just sending the csv path directly? Are the commands diverse enough that this will not work? I'm trying to better understand what you want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not executing the command in the function and compose the filename using `str.format` instead of using `exec` ?

```
def all_installs_to_dataframe(month):
    '''Imports csv's from different months to pandas dataframes'''
    dataset = pd.read_csv('/path/file2017{}_overview.csv'.format(month), sep=',', header=0, encoding='utf-16')
```

Comment: Merci for your answer Jean-Francoise Fabre. I tested it and this works perfectly fine. +1, when I get enough reputation.

Comment: @ccasimiro9444 you can accept the answer already. That doesn't require any privileges :)

Comment: Accepted it, I am new to this :)

Comment: oh yeah! :D and +1 for your great answer